# How to capture Haskell's library dependencies for FFI when building with `stack build`?

Tags: haskell-stack

I have a (very large) C/C++ project currently built with CMake. Development is primarily done on Windows. I would like to start developing some features with Haskell. For this reason, I'm trying to call Haskell functions from my existing C++ code. I've created a new Haskell project with `stack new` and am able to build it with `stack build`.

As I understand it, I now have to build my Haskell project and then configure CMake to link against it and Haskell's library dependencies. According to [FFI complete examples - When main is in C++](https://wiki.haskell.org/FFI_complete_examples#When_main_is_in_C.2B.2B) I could see these by running `ghc Foo.hs -v`, but this didn't seem to work when I tested it on their provided example (it did not contain any "-L" flags that I could see). I would preferably like whatever solution I find to not require manual editing of files, and work across Windows and Mac, but neither of these are strict requirements.